# In Far Cry 3 how can you equip a weapon you already own?

Tags: far-cry-3

I own an AK-47 (shows as "owned" in store/buy/assault rifile) but holding `1` for the weapon switcher just shows my M133 shotgun.

What happened to my AK-47? How can I equip it again?

Comment: Strange mechanic in the game, you can only "equip" weapons that you've "owned" at the gun store, or you can equip a gun you loot outside the store, depending on the weapon slots you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to one of the weapon shops, select the AK-47 and press 'Equip' at the bottom of the screen. That should do it :)

Comment: Answers should be based on a source or experience, maybe try to find a link that supports your answer.

Comment: It's from my own experience playing the game yesterday. Although I'm not certain to which key it was aligned.

Comment: Fair enough. But your answer sounds unsure. It would be a better answer if it was true (which it may very well be), and an even better one if it is verifiable - via link to the control scheme).

Comment: Ok, Once I get the time to launch the game I'll post my findings. :)

Comment: Updated, I was about right! ^^

Comment: @Thomas as I said in the original question, holding `1` does not show other weapons I already own...

Comment: Oh, then you have to go back to a shop. Select the weapon you want and press 'Equip' at the bottom.

Comment: Ah yes that's it, missed that button somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you have to be at the store or self serve in a safe house. Just act like you're going to buy a waapon, click on owned, select a slot.