# Finding lost weapons in Far Cry 3

Tags: far-cry-3

I tricked out a sniper rifle and had to drop it to pick up another weapon I needed and have since left that area and now its gone but in the gun store it still shows that I own it. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

Owning the gun is different than currently having it equipped. You can own all the guns, but only have up to 4 equipped at any given time. See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94569/in-far-cry-3-how-can-you-equip-a-weapon-you-already-own?rq=1) for answers on how to equip guns you already own.

Comment: I did own the gun. I bought it at the store, tricked it out and had to switch it out for another to complete the mission. Now I can't get it back. How do I get back weapons I already bought?

Comment: As stated in the answer I linked. Go to the weapon shop and "Equip" it. I believe the button is on the bottom of the screen.